# How to grab from right in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query and I'm using `split_part` to get value of from certain position:

```
split_part(fieldname,'{',12)
```

the result will be like this:

```
200;1;235}
200;1;237}
200;1;216}
```

my goal is to grab anything after the second `;`  like `(235,237,216)` as the number of character after `;` is not static

means sometimes it come 1,2,4 or even 5 digit and the number of character varies depending on the value.

How to do this?

Comment: Related to your other question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438549/splitting-data-based-on-some-character-in-postgres (just so other readers know). This data model is horrible, please use arrays of integer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
split_part( trim( '}' from split_part(fieldname,'{',12) ), ';', 3)
```

Please take a look at this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/978bd/5

Answer (score 2):

Try this: 
    `regexp_matches( split_part(fieldname,'{',12), '\d+;\d+;(\d+)}' )`

Comment: hi thanks for replay, before running this in main database I test it like this:

select regexp_matches('200;1;235}', '{\d+;\d+;(\d+)}')
and it return nothign

Comment: I am assuming the whole "fieldname" so you would match against '{200;1;235}' or even 'abc{200;1;235}xyz'