# Splitting data based on some character in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column like below. The column is variable means the length changes all the time:

```
{200;62;38;200;0;100
{200;62;38;200;0;100;200;0;100
{200;62;38;200;0;100;200;0;100;200;0;100
```

what I need to do is split this column in SQL as below

```
{200 62 38 200 0 100 200 0 100
```

this should come under their own column the goal so split them based on divider **;** this is a column in the table.

Comment: What is `{200 62 38 200 0 100 200 0 100`? An array of strings? A string with the semicolons replaced with spaces? Nine separate single column rows in a result set?

Comment: Do you want a single column returned and each element  should be one row? Or do you simply want to replace all `;` characters with a blank?

Comment: Urk, please read http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55871/postgresql-list-of-integers-separated-by-comma-or-integer-array-for-performance . Consider using an array instead.

Comment: Thanks for replay... what I want the out like:

field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 <br>
200     62     38     200    0      100

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved using [regexp_replace](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html):

```
select * from regexp_replace('{200;62;38;200;0;100', ';',' ','g')
```

The output is:

```
{200 62 38 200 0 100
```

Comment: can I do it like this 

 field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 
 200 62 38 200 0 100

Comment: It is not what you have asked for!

Comment: Yes but now I noticed that I have to sum those column individually... but the example I given could not do it individually...

Comment: Can you please give a complete example, and what you exactly expect to have as an output

Comment: What I want is to split those digit in their own column and sum each one of them under their own header like you do it in case

sum(case when i=1 then sal end) as "someheader"